# How to disable iDRAC status / alerts for absent PSU or input lost

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, power-supply-unit, dell-openmanage

I have a number of Dell PER740 servers running iDRAC 9 in a lab.

As they are in a lab, I only need/want/have capacity for one power supply connected to each server.

However, I cannot find a way to remove the alert/status that appear in the iDRAC (and also in OpenManage Enterprise) - like this one: [iDRAC Health Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxB53.png)

Such status appears when either the PSU is installed but disconnected ("input lost"), and also when the PSU is not in the server ("absent PSU").

I have disabled the power redundancy configuration, like: [disabled iDRAC power redundancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw0ht.png)

I have also disabled all Alerts in Configuration > System Settings > Alert Configuration > Alerts.

I have rebooted the iDRAC, and cleared the Event Log both in the iDRAC and using `racadm clrsel` - neither makes any difference...

All of this is to no avail.  I seem to be unable to get the servers to think they are single-PSU and yet healthy.  Is this possible?  I feel like my only option at the moment is to buy a power splitter cable...